# Search in one language but go to the website in another language

Tags: wordpress, seo

I know the title is a little complicated but the thing that I want is very simple.
I have a website running in English, but my visitors are located in Sweden. When a visitor search a phrase in Swedish, I want to make him/her to go to my English website. 
Example : searching for "äppelträd" but viewing my "apple tree" content

I know that Google does not use the keywords meta tag in web ranking. How can I manage to do that without them or else?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. That would be cheating Google. You will have to make your website multilingual if you want to be found based on Swedish keywords.

Comment: What if I am the producer of "apple tree" ? I don't want to cheat Google, just want to do it like alias for specific phrases.

Comment: Google suggests results based on the content it finds on your website. If it can't find "äppelträd" on there, it won't suggest your website. You could however add a little section like "Did you know that "äppelträd" is Swedish for "Apple Tree"? But that won't have much of the desired effect.

Comment: Thank you fellas, I will try something.